# How to make programmatical Mesh solid?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have added a mesh doing:

```
Mesh mesh;
void Awake() {
    mesh = GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh;
}
```

Now it shows up on the screen and everything, but I fall right through it. I have added a `MeshCollider`, but it shows `None (Mesh)` for `Mesh`, which might be the reason, but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: You have to set the `mesh` property to the mesh.

Comment: Set the mesh the mesh-collider uses -> `GetComponent<MeshCollider>().sharedMesh = mesh;` https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MeshCollider-sharedMesh.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your mesh vertices and uv.
There you have an example to make a single plane.
Need to replace the xpos,ypos and zpos with the coord of your desired points poisiton.

```
GameObject plane = new GameObject("Plane");
MeshFilter meshFilter = (MeshFilter)plane.AddComponent(typeof(MeshFilter));

Mesh mymesh = new Mesh();
mymesh.name = "MyCustomMesh";
mymesh.vertices = new Vector3[] {
     new Vector3(xpos, ypos, zpos),
     new Vector3(xpos, ypos, zpos),
     new Vector3(xpos, ypos, zpos),
     new Vector3(xpos, ypos, zpos),
 };
 mymesh.uv = new Vector2[] {
     new Vector2 (0, 0),
     new Vector2 (0, 1),
     new Vector2(1, 1),
     new Vector2 (1, 0)
 };
 mymesh.triangles = new int[] { 0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 3};
 mymesh.RecalculateNormals();

meshFilter.mesh = mymesh;
MeshRenderer renderer = plane.AddComponent(typeof(MeshRenderer)) as MeshRenderer;
```